# Getting error during using of driver.switchTo().alert() in WebDriver tests with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='submitButton']")).click();
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();// error message on eclipse  *Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.openqa.selenium.Alert to Alert*
String alertText = alert.getText();// The method getText() is undefined for the type Alert
alert.accept();// The method accept() is undefined for the type Alert
return alertText;
```

Getting error for `driver.switchTo().alert();` and `getText();` `accept();` method is undefined for the type alert.

Comment: Please do check for the proper imports... thanks...

Comment: Don't forget to come back to main window from alert by using  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import the following:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
```

The import statement mentioned above should solve the problem.